# Copying a Folder and renaming it using command prompt

Tags: batch-file, command, prompt

I am trying to copy a folder and paste it in the same directory it was copied from.

For example

C:\Test is the main directory which consists of a folder ACDM, I would like to copy ACDM in the same directory and rename the new folder to ACDM1 which will have all the same files as ACDM has

I would like to do it using command prompt

I tried the following

C:>Xcopy C:\Test C:\Test\ACDM1 /E /U
Cannot perform a cyclic copy
0 File(s) copied

which fails, not sure hoe to add REN command with XCOPY command.

Need help ASAP as i would want to create a batch file which will create a copy of an existing folder and rename it according to a name retrieved from a text file..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xcopy "C:\Test\ACDM\*.*" "C:\Test\ACDM1\" /s/h/e/k/f/c
```

Comment: Colin, the xcopy command creates the folder given and the backslash stops xcopy from asking if it is a folder.  You can see that the OP has reported that it works.

Comment: Well it's a good thing I didn't change it thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (yourtextfilename) do xcopy "C:\Test\ACDM" "C:\Test\%%a\" /E
```

as a .bat file line. Directly from the prompt, change each `%%` to `%`

I've assumed (for lack of futher information) that your textfile contains just the one line

```
ACDM1
```

- neither do you specify the textfilename tou want to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
 xcopy C:\Test\ACDM C:\Test\ACDM1\ /E /Q
```