# Using xcopy to copy files from 2 directories to one directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I am having trouble copying all .txt files from a folder(which has one sub_folder) into a different folder. I went through most of the existing threads and this is what I tried,

```
xcopy /s %logfolder%\*.txt  %monthlylogcopy%\
for /R %logfolder%  %f in (*.txt) do copy %f %monthylcopy%\
```

**Result**: In both these cases, only 1 .txt file is always copied from source to destination. There are over 20 .txt files in the folder and sub-folder.

**NOTE:** Used single '%' in 2) because I was running it in cmd.

PLease let me  know what I am missing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: check answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335159/windows-cmd-batch-for-r-with-delayedexpansion), I think it should help you.

Comment: Do you want the said sub-folder to be copied to the destination also, or do you want only its contents to be copied? What are the contents of your variables?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to add a backslash between *%logfolder%* and the file extension *.txt. The following command should work assuming that the variables actually contain valid paths:

```
xcopy /s "%logfolder%\*.txt" "%monthlylogcopy%\"
```

Comment: the "missing" backslash was actually there, but this site's formatting didn't show it. I properly formatted the code in the question.

Comment: Could you add the following commands at the bottom of your script and update your question with the result that they output? `set logfolder`, `set monthlylogcopy`, and `dir "%logfolder%"`

Comment: @Stephan, treintje Thank you for the response. The below answer worked for me  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21791974/7175940